# command.Parameters cannot convert type object to string

Tags: c#

I am trying to save the value passed by command.Parameters in a string variable but I am missing something to do that can anyone help to find out where is the issue. If you need more please do let me know I will update my description.

```
string message = command.Parameters["@type"].Value;
```

Comment: `command.Parameters["@type"].Value.ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do like this :

```
string message = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@type"].Value);
```

You can do `command.Parameters["@type"].Value.ToString()` too but it'll throw null exception if there is null value.`Convert.ToString()` will take care of null value and returns empty value if there is null.